# Limit with two parameters

Tags: calculus, limits

Let:
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {\frac{{{n^2} + 2n + 1}}{{{{\left( {4{n^2} + 6n + 2} \right)}^{\frac{{2m}}{k}}}}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{{2m}}}}$$

if $m=2k$ it's easy to see that the limit is ${1\over4}^{1\over 2m}$.
the two other cases are unclear to me:

When $2m < k$ the limit is  $\infty$ and when $2m > k$ the limit is $0$.
Why?

Comment: **Technique:** For a quotient of sums of terms that tend to infinity, locate the term that grows faster to infinity. Then, divide numerator and denominator by that term. The effect of this technique is that most of the resulting terms will now tend to either zero, or to a finite limit, or be bounded. The limit can often be deduced after this by applying the properties of limit with respect to the arithmetic operations of addition and division.

Comment: Following this technique we find that in the numerator we have $n^{2}$ while in the denominator we have $4^{2m/k}n^{4m/k}$. To decide which is faster tending to infinity we compare the exponents $2$ and $4m/k$. The cases you have correspond to $2<4m/k$, $2=4m/k$, and $2>4m/k$. In the first we use $n^{4m/k}$, in the second either term, and the in the last $n^2$ to divide numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that
$$(4n^2+6n+2)^{2m/k}\sim_\infty 4^{2m/k}n^{4m/k}$$
hence we have

$${\left( {\frac{{{n^2} + 2n + 1}}{{{{\left( {4{n^2} + 6n + 2} \right)}^{\frac{{2m}}{k}}}}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{{2m}}}}\sim_\infty4^{-1/k}n^{\frac1m-\frac{2}k}$$
Can you take it from here?